# ios unlock-keychain issue in jenkins-pipeline using groovy file

Tags: ios, shell, jenkins-groovy

**Context**

In the company they run many builds from blueocean/jenkins & they use iOS & MacOS

Many build fail with the error below randomly

**error message :**

```
    Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.

Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [sshPassword]

See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.

+ security unlock-keychain -p **** login.keychain

Sending interrupt signal to process
```

so I go to the documentation link but it didn't really help or/and I misunderstood it

I found the too lines in a groovy file

```
security unlock-keychain -p ${sshPassword} login.keychain
security set-keychain-settings -lut 1800 login.keychain
```

to me this is just looking good but this error make jenkins jobs to crash on different builds but always when this error occurs, so I guess this is the root cause.

how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

ok in fact, this runs on a setup that pop up a GUI windows.
So It needed to send someone on-site, to answer it.

to be sure machine is really ok, he also rebooted it.